# Chracterisation of Projective Line $\mathbb{P}^1_k$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I have a question about an argument used in Prop 50.10.4 for chracterisation of projective line $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ from https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0C6L

Let $k$ be a field and $X$ be proper.

Consider the implication (6) -> (1)

According to the source this is a consequence from 50.10.2: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0C6T

The problem is that 50.10.2 provides only a ***closed immersion*** $X \to \mathbb{P}^1_k$.

Why is it an ***isomorphism of schemes***?

My considerations: Since both are irreducible curves of dimension $1$ we conclude that $X$ is ***homeomorphic*** to $\mathbb{P}^1_k$ (as topological space) and by 50.10.2 a closed immersion as scheme morphism.

But does this already imply that it is an iso of ***schemes***?

Comment: It’s dominant, injective, and has closed image. Remember that curves are varieties in the Stacks Project so they’re reduced and irreducible.

Comment: @Samir Canning: So essentially (after having our closed immersion by 50.10.2) this problem indeed reduces to following statement: $R \to R/I$ is a ring map and $I=(0)$ iff $dim R = dim R/I$ (as Krull dimension),right? Since irreducible here imply that $I$ MUST be a prime

Comment: You also need reduced to get that $(0)$ is prime. More geometrically, just note that the map is dominant and injective so it’s birational. Birational maps between curves are isomorphisms (this comes earlier in the stacks project).

Comment: @SamirCanning: In your last statement you refer to 50.2.6 from https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0BXX ?

Comment: Yes that is what I had in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A closed immersion of schemes $f:X\to \mathbb{P}^1_k$ means that on an affine open $U=Spec(R)\subset \mathbb{P}^1_k$, we have $f^{-1}(U)$ isomorphic to $Spec(R/I)$ for an ideal $I\subset R$. Since $X$ is one dimensional, and since closed subsets of $\mathbb{P}_k^1$ are either finite or the entire space, this should give what you want.

Comment: I don't see how this information provides the desired result. Indeed locally on the ring level we have quotient maps $R \to R/I$ and obviously that suffice to verify that the corresponding ideal sheaf $\mathcal{I}$ is trivial/zero sheaf. Do you mean it in the sense that $1= dim X = dim U$ for every open non trivial set and then apply Krull dimension argumen for affine open sets? Or did I misunderstood you?

Comment: The problem that I see in your argument is that it might be possible that a scheme $Z$ can have different structure sheaf  (for example $O_X$ but also $O_X/I$ with $I= rad((0))$ but have the same underlying topological space...